# User authentication with RESTAS and Hunchentoot

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

(I use Hunchentoot and Restas, just thought that I would mention it up here too)

I don't really know how to do this stuff in general with HTTP, so I thought that maybe posting my code would be the simplest way to show my intent:

```
(define-route log-in ("/log-in/" :method :post)
  (multiple-value-bind (username pwd) (hunchentoot:authorization)
    (cond ((and (nth-value 1 (gethash username *users*)) ;; User exists
                (string= pwd (gethash username *users*)))) ;; Password is correct
          ;; Do something to keep track of logged in user
          )))
```

I basically just want to let a user log in, give him some sort of way to say "hey, it's me again" and some sort of way for me to say "Oh, hey! It *is* you again, here you go" and then serve the user a webpage.
I think that this should be done with cookies along with simply storing some value in a list that can be checked against the cookie.

How am I supposed to do this properly with Hunchentoot+Restas? Code and some explanation would be really awesome, I'm pretty lost here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `(start-session)` and then add a method like:

```
(defmethod handle-request :before ((acceptor acceptor) (request request))
   (unless (your-check-request-matches-login-page) ; skip session check on login page
       (if (null *session*)
          (redirect "/log-in")
          (progn
             (your-check-session-validity)
             (other-stuff)))))
```

The above method will work if you need to do authentication with a login page. But you need another way to get user and password from the user, as `(authorization)` will give you what the browser sent in the headers, and that is for basic-auth.

If you do really want to use basic-auth, then the browser will take care of poping-up a dialog to ask the user for credentials, so you don't need a login page. You need the following method, to intercept all requests and send the apropriate headers:

```
(defmethod handle-request :before ((acceptor acceptor) (request request))
    (multiple-value-bind (username pwd) (hunchentoot:authorization)
        (if (and (nth-value 1 (gethash username *users*)) ;; User exists
                 (string= pwd (gethash username *users*))) ;; Password is correct
            (progn
                ;; Do something here
            )

            (require-authorization "realm"))))
```

Comment: Also, `hunchentoot:authorization` is for basic-authorization. You need to call `(require-authorization "some-realm")` so Hunchentoot sends the right headers to the browser. The browser then asks the user for user and password and all requests will have attached the user+base64 encoded password *on the clear*. It's ok if you use HTTPS for all communications, but is insecure otherwise.